# Nginx configuration for NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, api, nginx

I have some static files, that I can already access, and I have an api, already at digital ocean.

But I am having some troble configuring NGINX to access both at the same time. If my api works, the static files don't. And vice-versa;

My api is running on port 5000, and I want to access the site and the api by IP adress.

Pls, help!

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name _;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    }

}

server {

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both services are being accessed from the same IP address and port, then you need to use one `server` block. Ideally, you would move the API into a unique URI, for example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass ...;
    ...
}
```

If you must use an overlapping URI space for both static files and the API, you can use `try_files` to check for the existence of a static file first:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    proxy_pass ...;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.